# Prepending plus sign and country code to phone number from form

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm currently using a form to get a phone number from the user, and they are directed to add area code but no spaces or dashes. It's validated here:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'phone_number' => 'digits:10'
]);
```

This works fine but I then need to send the phone number from the request

```
$sendNumber = $newCallFunction->phoneSubmission($request->phone_number);
```

as a string with '+' and the country code prepended to it. So in America the phone number they enter as 5555555555 should be sent in the function call as +15555555555

How should I set this properly using laravel?

Comment: Could you have users assign themselves to a country, and then have a table in your database, that gets areacode for that country, then send/store the number as is, then when you want to use it check the users account details, lookup the country code, and prepend it to the number and add a + manually?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I have used [Google's libphonenumber library](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) to validate and parse numbers. There's also a [php package](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) that works with larave that uses libphonenumber. The reason why I used this was because the library can validate numbers in different formats without any need to manipulate the input. Sharing as it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an associative array of the country code to the code code and then prepend that.

```
$countryCode = ['NL' =>'+075','US' =>'+1' ];
$sendNumber = $newCallFunction->phoneSubmission($countryCode['us' . $request->phone_number);
```

Depends on how you get the country tho